# Update record's foreign key field based on a newly inserted record's primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each record in table A I want to update the foreign key value of one of the fields based on new inserted record's scope_identity in table B.

I need to create a new record in table B for each record in table A in order to receive a foreign key(scope_identity) value.

For example, for each row in the following table I want to update the null Foreign Key field based on creating a new row/foreign key in Table B.

Table A:

```
|Id|ForeignKey|
|1 |NULL      |
|2 |NULL      |
|3 |NULL      |
|4 |NULL      |
|5 |NULL      |
```

As a pseudo code I thought of something like this sql:

```
update TableA 
set ForeignKey = (INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (value1) select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed this information. Removing the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a cursor to loop through TableA and create the records:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @ForeignKey int

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM TableA

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @Id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (value1)
    SET @ForeignKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE TableA
    SET ForeignKey = @ForeignKey
    WHERE Id = @Id

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @Id
END

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Answer (score 0):

The set-based way to do an UPDATE correlated with an INSERT in SQL Server 2008 and later is to use a [MERGE...OUTPUT](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx) statement.

```
-- This table variable will hold the correlation between the two tables
declare @NewLinks table (dst_id int, src_id int)

merge TableB dst
using TableA src
    on 1 = 0 --inserts all from src into dst, add WHERE-like limit here
when not matched --should never match, since this is an INSERT-like query
    insert (<dst_column_list>) values (<src_column_list>)
output INSERTED.<dst_surrogate_key>, src.<src_surrogate_key>
into @NewLinks

update src
set src.ForeignKey = nl.dst_id
from TableA src
join @NewLinks nl
    on nl.src_id = src.Id
```

Since the INSERT statement (even in the INSERT...SELECT form) doesn't have a FROM clause, `from_table_name` cannot be referenced in its OUTPUT clause to capture the full correlation. Since MERGE always considers its USING clause to be a FROM clause, it can be used to mimic the INSERT...SELECT construct while giving access to both source and destination tables in the OUTPUT.

Using MERGE...OUTPUT to create an UPDATE correlated to an INSERT replaces the the inefficient use of RBAR solutions using cursors or loops with the maintenance of a single temporary table or table-valued variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I found is using [ROW_NUMBER function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to arbitrarily join the tables, then use that derived query to update the FK. The idea is there isnt a relationship **yet** between tableA and tableB we just need link them to grab the new foreign keys. Joining them on something arbitrary like ROW_NUMBER gives us a method to pick out a single row to grab the Id from.

Create the new records first

```
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (value1)
```

Write the query that arbitrarily joins them on ROW_NUMBER (we use this in the next step)

```
SELECT
    tableARows.Id, 
    tableBRows.TheNewId
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Row =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM tableA
)tableARows INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TheNewId, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheNewId) FROM tableB
)tableBRows ON tableARows.Row = tableBRows.Row
```

And then a full UPDATE statement to populate tableA with new FK's from tableB

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.ForeignKey = LinkedKeys.TheNewId
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tableARows.Id, 
        tableBRows.TheNewId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id, Row =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM tableA
    )tableARows INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TheNewId, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheNewId) FROM tableB
    )tableBRows ON tableARows.Row = tableBRows.Row
)LinkedKeys INNER JOIN
tableA  ON tableA.Id = LinkedKeys.Id
```

Here are example table definitions I used.

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (Id INT, ForeignKey INT)
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (100,NULL),(200,NULL),(300,NULL)


CREATE TABLE tableB (TheNewId INT)
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES(5000),(6000),(7000)
```